# Solve Inverse Linear Congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse, congruences

I want to solve Linear congrunece : 9x+2 ≡ 6(mod 1453) using inverse of 9 mod 1453.
Inverse of 9 mod 1453 is 323. Now to solve it I subtract 2 from left and right side which gives me 9x ≡ 4(mod 1453), therefore x = 161. 161 is an answer to equation 9x ≡ 4(mod 1453)   , but answer is not correct to equation to 9x+2 ≡ 6(mod 1453). Can I state my answer then as (9*161)%1453 = 4 (or 9*161 ≡ 4(mod 1453)). Or did I mess up something during the calculating process.

Sorry for my English. It is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $9x\equiv 4\pmod{1453}$, we get $(323)(9)x\equiv (323)(4)\pmod{1453}$.

But $(323)(9)\equiv 1\pmod{1453}$, so we get
$$x\equiv (323)(4)\pmod{1453}.$$
Thus $x\equiv 1292\pmod{1453}$.

**Remark:** We have $1292\equiv -161\pmod{1453}$, so alternately we could say that $x\equiv -161\pmod{1453}$.